# Junit spring boot unable to autowire jdbc template

Tags: junit, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a Spring Boot application and worked fine with the application and previously with my JUNIT tests.

I have recently started using a JDBCTemplate and DataSource all of the tests fail to even start.

The main problem from the stacktrace is that once it tries to Autowire either the datasource or jdbc template it seems it cannot find the datasource properties

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'directoryLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.millerhare.winfsapi.fsloader.DirectoryLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
...
```

This is the Autowire class

```
@Component
public class DirectoryLoader {


@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
DataSource ds;
```

However in the application.properties for both the application and test, all of the datasource properties are set

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@xxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I have tried changing other properties like the server.port and those are picked up so it is clearly finding the application.properties file fine.

My original configuration for the test was

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = WinFsapiApplication.class)
 @WebIntegrationTest
```

I have also tried setting the properties via `@TestPropertiesSource` but this also does not find them.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have back-slashes in the datasource URL? The string should be `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx`. I believe the fact you have a `\` in there is causing the auto-detection of the driver (specifying the URL should be enough to detect the driver class, you wouldn't need to specify it).

Comment: Can't see why this is an issue. However when I don't use JUNIT and jsut run it works with or without the slashes. Removing them makes no difference.. it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where the spring boot application was running fine and I could test it from Postman but the JUnit tests were failing. Adding `application.properties` to `src/test/resources` resolved it for me.

I know spring boot should pick it up from `src/main/resources` but just wouldn't. Even if I asked it to look for it specifically using `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` on my configuration file.